# Accessible as in web accessibility

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, technical, technology

In web development the term *accessibility* is used when working with features such as screen readers. When talking about accessibility the wording sometimes makes it unclear whether one is referring to access or usability with assistive technologies.

Is there a better way to talk about accessibility to specifically refer to the assistive technologies, preferably in a single word?

I work with web accessibility, so this comes up quite frequently, and I would like to speak succinctly about accessibility on the web.

---

#### Example

I'm talking about poorly designed website: *the button is not accessible/inaccessible*. Here it is not clear that I'm talking about the button in relation to screen readers (the button might appear in TTS somewhere else), rather than the button not being visible or behind another element blocking it.

Comment: Thesaurus on [accessible](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/accessible) and [usable](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/usable) weren't of much use.

Comment: Why can't you use 'visible'? *The button is not visible*.

Comment: @WeatherVane OP literally said that's not what they are talking about. "*I'm talking about the button in relation to screen readers ... rather than the button not being visible*." And it appears the question is valid then, because you understood it in exactly the opposite way :)

Comment: @aoeu I would say something like "the accessibility of this button is poor." The word "accessibility" in that form specifically makes people instantly think about assistive technologies and such.

Comment: @Esther what's a TTS? Obviously, that paragraph was less than clear (or I would have got the correct sense when I read it). *I'm talking about poorly designed website*.

Comment: @WeatherVane TTS is text-to-speech, an assistive technology a vision-impaired person might use to "view" a website. The idea is that if a website is designed incorrectly, a computer parsing the page might position the button somewhere different than where it would appear on the page, or the TTS system may think it is an image rather than a button, or something like that. So to a person viewing the page it looks fine, but to someone having it read by a computer, it makes no sense.

Comment: @Esther I thought it might be related to the 'accessible' aspect, and was further thrown off by "the button might appear in TTS somewhere else". So it's on the visible page that the problems lies.

Comment: I should've written out the TTS abbreviation, my bad. @WeatherVane, you are correct in understanding the problem. That something _has poor accessibility_ would work, though I was hoping for something even shorter.

Comment: Another example of "buttons" with poor accessibility/which are inaccessible: The [All Sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) page for StackExchange. Using a mouse and eyes the page is easily navigable. However, if you try to select a site using _only_ the keyboard you will fail; it's not possible. Looking at the HTML tree (`right-click > inspect`) we see the reason: None of the sites are a button or link. They are unclickable, unfocusable images.

Comment: "access or usability with assistive technologies." Do you mean "usability with assistive technology or access"? I'm not sure how "access with assistive technology" would really make sense in context but I thought I would clarify.

Comment: Accessibility as you say means screen readers and text-to-speech. Done. Use it only that way. Obviously, we aren't going back to the days of *handicap access* and *sight-challenged*.

Comment: I don't think there's an explicit way to disambiguate this. There are contexts where "accessibility" is simply understood to refer to assistive technologies. For instance, Apple uses the name "Accessibility" in its Settings/Preferences applications, and everyone knows what it refers to.

Comment: This isn't something that can be summed up in one easy word. You probly need at least a sentence: _The button can't be accessed by X in Y because Z._

Comment: @YosefBaskin it *includes* screen readers/TTS, but *means* a far wider range of tools - think of technology for those who can't use a mouse (keyboard navigation was mentioned above, for example). Buttons that don't zoom usefully when the body text does would be another accessibility fail for those whose vision needs non-standard settings, as would low contrast that doesn't respond to the usual easy solutions. Or the opposite - mercifully rare on websites - reliance on audio with no fallback

Comment: It depends who you are talking to. As @BenjaminHarmin writes, providers of technical hardware and software to the general public use the term (Apple does this on iOS, and with all due respect has more user interface experience than other companies). However if you were talking outside the context of technical devices to a non-techie, you would have to spell it out.

Comment: @aoeu so you *are* talking about a button that can't be seen? please, please rephrase your last paragraph; it sounds like exactly the opposite of what you are looking for

Comment: @Steve, that is precisely the meaning aoue ***doesn't*** want.

Comment: @aoeu +1 for a question that does an excellent job of identifying the lack of knowledge and understanding of accessibility issues among the 'abled' community.

Comment: "Accessible" seems to be the commonly used adjective in technical contexts: [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/make-your-word-documents-accessible-to-people-with-disabilities-d9bf3683-87ac-47ea-b91a-78dcacb3c66d), [W3C](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tips/designing/). I'm not sure it would ever really be ambiguous in context. "The control is not accessible" would be an odd way of saying it was hidden or invisible. But if you're adamant it is unacceptable, you will have to reword sentences.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"[Accessibility](https://www.peatworks.org/futureofwork/a11y/#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9CAccessible%20technology%E2%80%9D%20is%20technology%20that,best%20for%20him%20or%20her.)" *is* the word you're looking for.

In the context of tech, the word "accessibility" now refers exclusively to assistive technologies, technologies to assist differently abled people, like on my Sony Bravia, if I want to find the options for closed captioning, I find them in the "Settings" menu under the submenu "Accessibility."

Note that "accessibility" is a different word than "accessible," "inaccessible," and "access," all alternate words you mention. While the root word "access" is the same, all other forms of the word "access" are still used more generically, like in your example, *"...the button is not accessible/inaccessible."*

In tech, whether it be websites, phones, smart TVs, or whatever, "accessibility" is *the* keyword used for referring to assistive technologies for differently abled people, and it is used exclusively for this purpose. All other forms of the word "access" continue to mean what they've always meant *unless* used in conjunction with and/or in a context that expressly refers to "accessibility."

So, as I said at the start, the word you're looking for is the one you gave: "accessibility." As long as you don't use "accessibility" in regard to tech with any generic sense but solely for referring to aspects of tech having to do with differently abled people, there will be no confusion because "accessibility" *is* the operative word in the context of tech. In tech, if one hears or reads "accessibility," one can rest assured that what's being discussed is assistive technologies for differently abled people, but if the word "accessibility" isn't anywhere present, isn't used to introduce what's being discussed, one can rest assured that "access" and all its other forms simply carry on meaning what they've always meant without any narrowing to just aspects having to do with differently abled people.

Yes, that means you may need to reword some things sometimes, like in a situation *not* having to do with differently abled people where you want to write, "The button is not accessible," like your example, you'd write exactly that instead of writing something like, "The button lacks accessibility," because you'd know that using the keyword "accessibility" throws up a flag for readers and would stand to imbue what you'd be saying with a meaning other than what you'd intend.

By the way, this use of "accessibility" may have started as jargon, but it's gone well beyond jargon and into the common vernacular as people in general are increasingly aware and expected to be aware of this special meaning for "accessibility" when it regards the tech they use every day, like how Sony expects me and all its customers, the general public, to simply know from reading the word "Accessibility" alone with no other cues or clues that selecting it is how you find any and all of the device's options having to do with differently abled people, like closed captioning options.

Comment: Or: Context is everything.

Comment: The OP actually wants to unequivocally refer to the assistive-technologies meaning of "accessiblity", so when you say things like 'All other forms of the word "access" continue to [...] mean what you want them to mean', it's a bit confusing.

Comment: The only answer fully addressing brevity and clarity when referring to accessibility vs something being accessible. Your answer also extends to meat-space where, e.g. a doorknob is accessible but has poor accessibility. The answer is a bit lengthy and repetitive. Lacking references.

Answer (score 2):

One option is "AT accessible". In certain circles this won't need a definition but most of the time you'll need to explain that "AT" is assistive technology (and what exactly that includes too). [Visa's documentation](https://developer.visa.com/pages/accessibility/interaction/int-001) provides an example in use:

> Code keyboard and assistive technology (AT) accessible forms

(Note: While almost everyone uses keyboards, I believe that they are a type of AT, since certain users, such as those with motor impairments, need to use a keyboard to navigate.)

The downside of referring to AT specifically is that a lot of accessibility problems don't necessarily involve AT at all, such as poor color choice (which affects colorblind users who don't tend to use any special tools). But in that case you could say it's not "colorblind accessible".

Comment: '[WCAG Accessible](https://www.w3.org/WAI/standards-guidelines/wcag/)' would work too

Comment: eh, my entire job is accessibility based web design and I had to do a double take at "AT accessibility" and think about what it meant. I'd definitely prefer ADA or WCAG over AT, but I'm based in the US where those are what govern accessibility requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Without speaking to the more lexical/grammatical aspects of the word `accessibility` I can say that in my experience as a designer and developer such things are usually referred to as "poor user experience (UX)."  As in: "When you first come on the site this button isn't visible, which leads to a poor user experience."

This can easily be extended to accessibility concerns: "...which leads to a poor user experience for people using screen readers."

Answer (score 0):

You could say "the button has poor accessibility", it's unlikely to be understood as "the button cannot be accessed".

Answer (score 0):

During the creation of DHS Trusted Tester, we avoided citing specific additive technologies in the test process.

The generic 'user agents, including assistive technologies (AT)' was used to allow for any assistive technology that used the built in operating system or platform accessibility services (or OS Accessibility APIs).

If you want specific testing with a specific assistive technology, cite that product *by version* and have tests done with that particular AT. Typically, the one the host organization would be providing or has standardized to be provided for any people with disabilities as an accommodation.

E.g., "Test with NVDA", "Test with iOS Voice Over", etc.

Note: not all AT is the same, software AT behaves differently, and you'll be led down a path of submitting bug reports for expected versus discovered and standards guidelines.

DHS Trusted Tester Program resources https://www.dhs.gov/publication/dhs-section-508-compliance-test-processes and
Section 508 ICT Testing Baseline
https://ictbaseline.access-board.gov/
may be of use to you.